# Find the fallacy: $2+2=4-\frac92+\frac92=\sqrt{(4-\frac92)^2}+\frac92=\cdots=5$

Tags: radicals, fake-proofs

I am unable to spot the mathematical technicality error in the riddle below.

[image]

Plese elucidate this to me.

Comment: $$\left(4-\frac{9}{2}\right)^2 = \left(5-\frac{9}{2}\right)^2$$, yet $$\left(4-\frac{9}{2}\right) \ne \left(5-\frac{9}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

The fallacy is in thinking $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. Actually, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: I guess your answer is the only correct answer here, so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since $4-9/2 <0$, it's not true that $4-9/2=\sqrt{(4-9/2)^2}$

Comment: The square root is applied "AFTER" the subtraction, so the sign is always positive.

Comment: @NoChance: The "proof" substitutes $\sqrt{(4-\frac92)^2}$ (a positive value) for $4-\frac92$ (a negative value).

Comment: @Blue, thank you. The answer was not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both of these answers - essentially the value in the first square root is $ (-0.5)^2$ , i.e. $0.25$, this stays the same through all values in the subsequent square roots until the last when this is written (correctly) as $0.5^2$.

So all steps look okay, but the overall argument rests on the (incorrect) statement that $x^2 = y^2$ implies $x=y$, a very relevant counter example to this being that $(-0.5)^2$ = $0.5^2$ but $-0.5 <> 0.5$.